# Specify options while saving Spark DataFrame as Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, compression

I use MongoSpark to read JSON-data from a MongoDB database as a Spark DataFrame. Now I want to write the JSON-data residing in the DataFrame as Parquet-files and that works like a charm. However, I'm struggling to set compression related options for the generated Parquet-files. I'd like to use Snappy as the codec and also would like to generate "larger" files by specifying the block size for the generated Parquet-files. I don't know how many different approaches I've tested so far but they're numerous. I thought this would be a straightforward thing to do by just "chaining" some `.option(...)` statements to the `DataFrame.write()` method but so far I've been unsuccessful in my efforts.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec","snappy")

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. set the `spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec` configuration in spark to `snappy`. This would be done before creating the spark session (either when you create the config or by changing the default configuration file).
2. `df.write.option("compression","snappy").parquet(filename)`

Comment: Hi Assaf! I did the following: df.sqlContext().setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy") and that solved the compression codec issue. Hmmm, now I only need to find a remedy for specifying the block-size of the generated Parquet.files... :)

Comment: Since you are using sqlContext I imagine you are using an older version of spark. You can try this for the block size:     val blockSize = 1024 * 1024 * 16      // 16MB
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt( "dfs.blocksize", blockSize )
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.setInt( "parquet.block.size", blockSize )

Comment: I don't use sqlContext but by df.sqlContext.setConf(...) I was available to specify the alternate compression codec (snappy) when writing out my DataFrame. I thought I would be able to do the same by just specifying a df.write().option(...) but so far I have been unsuccessful doing it this way. The df.sqlContext().setConf(...) solved that part though...

Comment: df.write.option("compression","snappy").parquet(filename) didn't work? it works for me on spark 2.1.1

Comment: I use Spark 1.6 and it didn't work :( df.sqlContext().setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec‌​", "snappy") works and I leave that for now - we'll migrate in the near future so some "refactoring" will be done to the codebase :)